# Triggering an Event on KeyPress is too CPU Consuming

Tags: jquery

I am using the following script to filter out divs that do not contain text in an inbox. (Similar to friends tab on Facebook)

```
$('#friend_search_form input').keyup(function(){
    var $searchString = $(this).val();
    $('.buddy').show();
    $('.buddy_name > a:contains('+$searchString+')').closest('.buddy').hide();
    console.log($searchString);  
})
```

The problem is when  you are typing, it takes a lot of resources and get buggy.

What is the better way to write this?

Comment: This is probably a better question for http://s.tk/review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of running your code every keypress, why not wait until the user stops typing for a period of time?

```
var typingTimeout;

$('#friend_search_form input').keyup(function(e) { 
  if (typingTimeout != undefined) {
    clearTimeout(typingTimeout);
  }

  typingTimeout = setTimeout(function() {        
    var $searchString = $(this).val();

    $('.buddy').show();
    $('.buddy_name > a:contains('+$searchString+')').closest('.buddy').hide();
    console.log($searchString);  
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Alternately, [use a plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/). Debouncing is the right idea, though.

Comment: Try @MДΓΓБДLL's plugin. As I don't have a demo to test this code with, I'm writing it blindly.

Answer (score 0):

Using only a class name as a selector is *way* slower than for example an ID or even specifying the tag name as well as the class. You could also narrow the selector down by starting with an ID, something like this: `$('#buddies div.buddy');` (immediately finds the #buddies element then only needs to match div element's class names) instead of just `$('.buddy')` (which goes through *every* element on the page and tries to match the class name).