# Jquery background request using $.get() with ASP.NET - Solving Issues

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am working on an ASP.NET application that makes some AJAX background request using jQuery (I'm new to jQuery :)).
My jQuery codes are as following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#ctl00_cphContent_txtOrgName").keypress(function () {

            var orgNameLen = $("#ctl00_cphContent_txtOrgName").val().length;
            if (orgNameLen <= 4) {
                $("#orgNameHints").empty();
                $("#orgNameHints").css('display', 'none');
                return;
            }
            $("#orgNameHints").css({ "visibility": "visible" });
            $("#orgNameHints").html("Checking...");
            var OrgName = $(this).val();
            $.get("ProcessOrgName.aspx?n=" + OrgName, function (data) {
                $("#orgNameHints").html(data);
                $("#orgNameHints").show();
            });
        });
        $("#ctl00_cphContent_txtOrgName").blur(function () {
            $("#orgNameHints").empty();
            $("#orgNameHints").css({ "visibility": "hidden" });
        });
    });
```

And ASP codes are:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOrgName" runat="server" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
<div id="orgNameHints" style="border: 1px solid silver; display:none; position:absolute; padding: 5px; background: #EFEFEF; z-index: 100;"></div>
```

Here `txtOrgName` is the textbox that is used to check existing records with same data in background (Just like the hinting of search keywords in google). The .get() method will post the search keyword as querystring at `ProcessOrgName.aspx`, which returns the list of such existing records from the database.

Everyting works fine here, but the problems I am facing are:

1. Keypress() event invokes search like, if I am searching for
   **stackoverflow** it will query for **stackoverflo** where **w** is missing. So, is there any way to get accurate result.
2. When I search for a keyword it is displays fine, but when I press backspace
   to clear my textbox, it will still display the same results untill I
   press backspace 2 times more after the textbox is already clear. So,
   can u guys please give any idea to make it so that it does not
   display the result in case I press backspace.
3. Any other way to display and hide the div named `orgNameHints` as show(); and hide(); does not work in my case, and I want it to be more accurate!
4. There will be some instances when the user will copy-paste the keywords instead of typing, so it should get search results in that case as well.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: binding an actual method directly to keypress event isn't a good approach, I recommend you read the answer to my question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627175/better-way-to-write-this-in-jquery

Comment: Thanks @Atif, but that is just a suggestion for improving the search but does not actually solves the issue. I'll make the amendments as mentioned in there. Please help me with the actual issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This could be a result of when you are capturing the text; keypress/keyup/keydown.  I think you might want to run this script on keyup() event.  Refer to http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/KeyPress-KeyDown-KeyUp-The-Difference-Between-Javascript-Key-Events.aspx for more information on this.
2. Refer to 1
3. Why does show/hide not work?  Alternatively, you could use fadeIn/fadeOut or $("elem").css({display:none})
4. For pasting (CTL+V), I believe that is on a keydown() event, if (e.keyCode == 86) //86 is Paste event.  As far as a mouse paste, I am not sure..couldn't find any good info on this.

Here is a starter block of code for you, with a fiddle link below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function DoWork(){
    $("#searchOutput").append("<li>" + $("#tb1").val() + "</li>");
    }
$("#tb1").keyup(DoWork);
    $("#tb1").keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 86){
            DoWork();
        }
    });        
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/CnDGw/3/

Best of luck!